# Android: Store a boolean on the device

Tags: android, authentication

I have an app which uses a login using Google+. 
I want the login screen to appear only for the first time, and then when the user logs out of the app. What should I do for this?
I'm using this as the firstActivity for the app.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class firstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I do not know how to create a variable which can be assigned a value and be stored on the device, which will only be changed on logging out. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Add the value in a `SharedPreference` and change it during Log in and Log out. Refer [this](http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/05/demo-shared-preference.html) link. After Log In store the value in `sharedPreference` and after Log out clear the value in `sharedPreference`

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreference` to store short information. It is best suite for your requirement.
[SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: Will it be a global variable and be accessible across all activities, as I have to set it to false when the person logs out?

Comment: It is specific to application. It can be accessible to all activities in application.

Answer (score 0):

Save a variable with a value in SharedPreferences first time when you login, then every time when you login check the saved value. When you logout you can re-write that value so that when you launch the app again since the value saved is different it will login.

To save a value to shared preferences you need to do the following:
The following is to save a string variable: Here MyData is the name of File in which value will be stored.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("position", Long.toString(id));
                    editor.commit();
```

You can retrieve the saved value as shown below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String position = sharedPreferences.getString("position", "0");
```

You can use as it suits you.

Hope this helps you.